# Быстрый поиск по сайту

Tags: jquery

Есть сайт, библиотека с около 1К книг (html файлов). Нужно было организовать поиск. Задачу выполнил с помощью алгоритма: 1. загрузка (AJAX) первого файла во временный контейнер, 2. поиск и отображение элементов с совпадением, 3. очистка временного контейнера. 4. загрузка (AJAX) второго файла во временный контейнер ... Все работает отлично, но скорость поиска очень низкая. Все скрипты писал на JQuery.

Как задачу организации поиска нужно было бы сделать по умному, чтобы быстро получать результаты?

Comment: Поставить полноценный поисковый движок на сервере